# Can I query for Custom Label Translations?

Tags: soql, tooling-api, translation-workbench

I need to see what custom labels I have provided translations for, but the interface in Setup does not make this easy. Is it possible to query for this information or access it via an API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to query for these translations by querying for [`ExternalStringLocalization`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_externalstringlocalization.htm). Example:

```sql
SELECT Id
  ,ExternalStringId
  ,ExternalString.MasterLabel
  ,ExternalString.Value
  ,Value
  ,Language 
FROM ExternalStringLocalization 
ORDER BY ExternalString.MasterLabel, Language
```

If you use the Developer Console, ensure you check "Use Tooling API".